# PHP Database Results > Array > JSON (without deprecated mysql_fetch_assoc)

Tags: php, json

I've been searching everywhere for a definitive answer to what seems to be a really simple task - unfortunately all the solutions I can find (and there are a lot) use mysql_fetch_assoc which is deprecated.

All I'm trying to do is to take a two column set of results from a database and echo in JSON format - I've managed everything fine except for one bit - I can't work how to get the values in to a two dimensional array (two column array) using array_push.  I just end up with my two column values merged in to one array.  Here's a stripped version of what I've done:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$mostPopularStm = $sparklyGenericPdoObj->prepare("SELECT views, thing FROM X");
$mostPopularStm->execute();
$mostPopularRS = $mostPopularStm->fetchAll();
echo '{data:';
$mostPopularJson = array();
foreach ($mostPopularRS as $mostPopularItem)
{
array_push($mostPopularJson, $mostPopularItem["views"], $mostPopularItem["thing"]);
}
echo json_encode($mostPopularJson);
echo '}';
```

This is producing output like this:

```
{data:["Monkeyface","43","Giblets","25","Svelte","22","Biriani","21","Mandibles","20"]}
```

But what I need is this:

```
{data:["Monkeyface":"43","Giblets":"25","Svelte":"22","Biriani":"21","Mandibles":"20"]}
```

I know I can create something manually to do this, using json_encode to format the string on each loop but it seems inefficient.

Any pointers would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Your wanted JSON is invalid. Array is an ordered list of values - not of key-value pairs, that is an object. Also `data` needs quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current array is like

```
array(0 => 'Monkeyface', 1 => 43, /* ... */);
```

but you need like

```
array('Monkeyface' => 43, /* ... */);
```

Replace

```
array_push($mostPopularJson, $mostPopularItem["views"], $mostPopularItem["thing"])
```

By

```
$mostPopularJson[$mostPopularItem["thing"]] = $mostPopularItem["views"];
```

And

```
echo '{data:';
echo json_encode($mostPopularJson)
echo '}';
```

Better to use:

```
echo json_encode(array('data' => $mostPopularJson));
```

As kingkero said, you will never get your expected result because it is invalid:

```
{data:["Monkeyface":"43" ...
```

Correct:

```
{ "data": { "Monkeyface": "43" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I understand that 'data' needs quotation marks - its just that some FLOT examples I've seen omitted them.
In your second JSON example, you've used no square brackets but json_encode is creating the square brackets (not me) - am I missing something?

Comment: The square brackets indicate an array `['test', 123]`, and a json array never has a key, the index is just the position of the element. The `{` brackets indicate objects (or php associative arrays): `{'test': 123}`. `json_encode` creates the `[` because your array is not like you think it is :-)

Answer (score 1):

Compose your array like so:

```
$mostPopularJson [$mostPopularItem["thing"]] = $mostPopularItem["views"];
```